# Why didn't the Bumblebee Driver take effect after installing it and rebooting?

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

How I attempted to install bumblebee:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

Using this script, I have the following output about my graphics / xorg setup.
https://gist.github.com/NullVoxPopuli/5724159

Output:

```
Graphics Card(s): 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 730M] (rev a1)

Connected Monitors: 
[     7.244] (II) intel(0): Output LVDS1 connected
[     7.244] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 connected

Current Video Driver: 
drm_kms_helper         49394  1 i915
drm                   286313  4 i915,drm_kms_helper

Video Output Locations: 
/dev/video0
/dev/fb0
/dev/dri/card0
/dev/dri/controlD64

Grub boot command: 
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-23-generic root=UUID=465876a7-4c66-4160-822f-9c1d5cd30037 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7

modprobe.d drivers: 
/etc/modprobe.d/
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-modem.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-oss.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-304_hybrid.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-firewire.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-watchdog.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/vmwgfx-fbdev.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/dkms.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf

Do we have a xorg.conf file?
ls: cannot access /etc/X11/xorg.conf: No such file or directory

glxinfo: 
/home/me/scripts/which-graphics-driver: line 25: glxinfo: command not found

Drivers loaded by Xorg: 
[     5.954] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     5.958] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[     5.961] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     5.962] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[     5.963] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[     5.966] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     7.244] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[     7.523] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[     7.534] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
```

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04

### UPDATE (summary of comments):

`optirun app-name` produced an error, so I installed the package it suggested (`mesa-utils`, I think?) and tried `optirun firefox` and got this error:
`[ 2971.281588] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver [ 2971.281649] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.1`

Next, was to check the `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` file, and see if it had the correct BusID. It didn't, so I changed it from `PCI:01:00:0` to `PCI:01:00.0`.. but I got the same error. :-(
Here is my current `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` file if anyone is curious: http://pastebin.com/HreaubsF

it was suggested that I run `glxinfo` from the terminal, but that has a TON of output that I don't know how to read.

As of June 12th, 2013 9:48pm EST, I still have this error when trying to use optirun:

```
$ optirun firefox
[111951.191738] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) No devices detected.

[111951.191804] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

Comment: You have to run `optirun app-name` in terminal to use the nvidia card. Everything else will the integrated graphic card be used for..

Comment: this is what I get when I do optirun <anything>
`[ 2971.281588] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

[ 2971.281649] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.1`

Comment: Hm, strange.. When I run that script I got allmost the same, apart from GLXinfo, where I got things right.. But I have nvidia-current installed...

Comment: when I was watching bumblebee install, I saw it also included nvidia-304 and nvidia-current. 
so.. I have the packages installed. I guess they just aren't active?

Comment: Try to run `lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'` in terminal..

Comment: If you edit the the file `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` you will see you need the BusID.. Uncomment that line to be something like: `BusID "PCI:01:00:0"` (example from the file).

Comment: @aXept that command yields what I have under "Graphics Cards" in my script output

Comment: @aXept I seed the BusID line. It is already uncommented, and has the correct number thing, 01:00:0.

Comment: Then something else is wrong :P Hope you get a answer for this!

Comment: Me too. I've not had any luck with graphics drivers. I just recently re-installed ubuntu after fighting for a few weeks with proprietary Nvidia 319.23 (or was it .21? idk) >_< 
I've been making regular snapshots this time though, in case something goes wrong. haha. Re-setting everything up sucks. haha

Comment: Use:
`lspci | grep VGA`
and find your nvidia controller.
It will look something like:
`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF106M [GeForce GT 555M] (rev a1)`

But with your controller. Take the first number (01:00.0 in my case) and put that in your xorg.conf.nvidia file instead of 01:00.0.

During instillation Bumblebee puts 01:00.0 in the file assuming it is correct, and asking you to change it if it isn't.

Comment: Hm, in that config file its: `1:00:0` but it should be `1:00.0` with just a dot. Checked that?

Comment: I changed 1:00:0 to 1:00.0. Same optirun error. :-\

Comment: If you run `glxinfo` in terminal?

Comment: If I was you I would try to install nvidia-current-updates.. Worth a try..

Comment: Btw, how's your bumblebee.conf look like?

Comment: bumblebee.conf http://pastebin.com/HreaubsF
I don't have glxinfo installed right now. I'll do that.
(I'm reeeeaaaalllly worried about manually installing nvidia-anything)

Comment: what input do you want from glxinfo? there is a lot

Comment: Nah, just thought since it was missing in the script before.. But nevermind about the outcome. The bumblebee.conf file looks like mine, but take a look at this, maybe you find a solution: https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/364#issuecomment-15642141

Comment: Maybe you should try to remove bumblebee completely and reinstall from beginning..

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli - please can you copy & paste / summarise the above and put this into your question.  We can then tidy stuff by deleting the comments.  At the moment its very difficult to understand what the current position is with this question.  Thanks.

Comment: summarized! (under "update" section in question)